# Is there a way to get back a result from a PWA I develop to Android using a startActivityForResult from the native app?

Tags: javascript, java, android, http

I am trying to use a PWA I develop with HTML and JavaScript to process data and send it back to the Android app.

The Android should open the PWA after the user clicks a button for example, I already did this by starting an activity with an intent using the page URL:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://examplePWA.com/"));
Log.d(TAG, "onClick() called with: view = [" + browserIntent.getDataString() + "]");
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

What I want now is to get a response intent from the PWA to a `startActivityForResult (browserIntent, 123);`
sent from Android for example.

How can I do this from the PWA side, is it possible to send an Android Intent from a PWA using JavaScript or any other way?

Comment: As far as i know there is no direct way to start an android activity from a web application, but you could try setting up a deeplink that will start the activity. Then link to that in the web app.

Comment: hmm but you still wouldn't be able to send data from the web app right? just trigger an activity on the app

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, for the purpose of starting an activity from within the javascript env, you could employ the [@JavascriptInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface) which will allow you to invoke Java methods inside your javascript code (if you use `WebView`).

```java
class WebBridge {

  @JavascriptInterface
  public void openBrowser(String href) {
    // .. start your activity here
  }

}

// Somewhere where you initialize your WebView
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebBridge(), "AndroidWebBridge");

// Inside your javascript app code
window.AndroidWebBridge.openBrowser("https://google.com");
```

The code below illustrates the overall concept, not a copy-paste solution. Hope that helps your.

Comment: thank you! i saw this as a possible method to use the javascript functions on my pwa in the app but i was more keen on anything that wouldn't involve changing too much code on the android app side, so that developers wouldn't need to change their apps code in order to use the pwa also..

Comment: You're welcome! Additional thoughts - you can make a well-documented AndroidWebBridge API for the web part of your PWA app. This API will comprise both `openBrowser` method and all other methods that you'd eventually like to implement, so that'd be standard tool across all web engineers in your team.